# Bayes Learning - MAP hypotesis

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian

Suppose I have a set of hypotesys H = {h1, h2} mutual exclusive. For them P(h1) = 0.2 and p(h3) = 0.3 (prior distribution).
Suppose we know also that

P(Y=0 | h1) = 0.2
P(Y=0 | h2) = 0.4

where Y is an attribute (target) that can have two values {1,0}. 
Suppose finally that you observe the event Y = 0.

Which one is the MAP (Maximum a posteriori) hipotesys?

- MAP is h1
- MAP is h2
- there's no enough element to find MAP
- MAP h1 = MAP h2
- nobody of the possible answer above

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math, not programming.

Comment: @larsmans you're right but I'm under pression for an exam of my course of computer science, and i was thinking that someone here could know the answer. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such question should be asked (and now probably migrated) on the math.stackexchange.com or stats.stackexchange.com .

Your question is basic application of the [Bayes Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem)

```
              P(Y=0|h1)P(h1)    0.2*0.2    0.04
P(h1|Y=0) =   -------------   = ------- = ------
                  P(Y=0)         P(Y=0)   P(Y=0)

              P(Y=0|h2)P(h2)    0.3*0.4    0.12
P(h2|Y=0) =   --------------  = ------- = ------
                  P(Y=0)         P(Y=0)   P(Y=0)
```

So the `h2` is the more probable hypothesis, as `P(Y=0)>0`

Comment: thank you. I asked this question also on math.stackexchange.com but nobody give me an answer. I have another case: if instead of know that P(Y=0 | h1) = 0.2 P(Y=0 | h2) = 0.4 I have P(Y=1 | h1) = 0.2 P(Y=0 | h2) = 0.4 the result change and MAP hypotesis become h1 right(P(h1|Y=0) = 0.16 AND P(h2|y=0) = 0.12)? And last question: if I understood well the sum of prior probability is not needed to be 1. Is that right?

Comment: If you have the `P(Y=1|h1)` and know that `Y` takes only two values, then `P(Y=0|h1)=1-P(Y=1|h1)` and the calculations are analogical. Priors sum to `1` across possible events, where events are `{h1 and h2,h1 and not h2,not h1 and h2,none}`, which is obviously not the case for just knowing `P(h1)` and `P(h2)`, but as they are mutualy exclusive, you have that `P(h1)+P(h2)+P(not h1,not h2)=1`